# How to send card id to the menu items using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

My objective is to pass the id for `handleClick` function, If i click on the 3 dots of the respective card then it should reflect particular card id. Can anyone help me in giving id for handle Click arrow function.

Here is the code:

```
 state = { menu: null };
  handleClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({ menu: e.target });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ menu: null });
  };

{Data.map(user => (
          <CardHeader
            key={user.id}
            className={classes.header}
            avatar={<Avatar aria-label="recipe">R</Avatar>}
            action={
              <div className={this.state.menu && classes.menu}>
                <IconButton
                  id="simple-menu"
                  className={classes.showIcon}
                  aria-label="settings"
                  aria-controls="simple-menu"
                  onClick={this.handleClick}
                >
                  <MoreVertIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <Menu
                  style={{ marginTop: "35px" }}
                  id="simple-menu"
                  keepMounted
                  anchorEl={this.state.menu}
                  open={Boolean(this.state.menu)}
                  onClose={this.handleClose}
                >
                  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>View</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>hide</MenuItem>
                </Menu>
              </div>
            }
            title={user.title}
            subheader={user.subheader}
          />
        ))}
```

[here is the sample one](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-menu-button-visibility-fix-rminv)

Comment: You’re passing the whole event to your state instead of the id alone. Try to log ‘e.target’

Comment: @SecondSon - Hi, It is showing undefined.

Comment: are you trying to pass the user id or?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the function and pass the id to it. Like

```
handleClick = (id, e) => {
    console.log(id)
    this.setState({ menu: e.target, id: id });
};

<IconButton
   id="simple-menu"
   className={classes.showIcon}
   aria-label="settings"
   aria-controls="simple-menu"
   onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, user.id)}
   >
   <MoreVertIcon />
</IconButton>
```

or instead of binding the function you can create a new arrow function and pass the id like this:

```
<IconButton
   id="simple-menu"
   className={classes.showIcon}
   aria-label="settings"
   aria-controls="simple-menu"
   onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(user.id, e)}
>
   <MoreVertIcon />
</IconButton>
```

You can save the id in states and then use it in the menu component to perform further actions

Comment: Hi, Still it is showing undefined. I've updated my sandbox code, could you please preview it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick solution for that kind of situations. Also this is most performant solution. You won't need to create arrow function instance for every re-render or each React node.

```js
<IconButton
  id="simple-menu"
  className={classes.showIcon}
  aria-label="settings"
  aria-controls="simple-menu"
  onClick={this.handleClick}
  data-user-id={user.id} // Define your user id as native data attribute
>
```

And then get data attribute of your current clicked element.

```js
handleClick = (e) => {
  const { userId } = e.currentTarget.dataset; // Get your data-user-id value as string

  console.log(Number(userId));

  this.setState({ menu: e.target, id: Number(userId) }); // Convert to number and save to state
};
```

So you can create your own scenarios up to your depends.

---

In this case, also you might want to learn `event bubbling` logic to understand the difference between `target` and `currentTarget` use case.

Also you can check it out for more information about data-* attributes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes